# How to hide and show Floating Button on top of FlatList when user reached the bottom or top?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, floating-action-button

I have a flatlist componment which renders some data and on the bottom there is a floating action button which does some things. The button is using absolute position and it is always on center bottom.

When the user scrolls down I want the button to dissapear.When he scrolls up I want the user to show the button. Is that possible in react native?

My main component that renders Header, Body, and the Floating Button:

```
const Main = ({navigation, route}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Header/>
          <Body data={route.params.item}/>
          <FloatingButton data={route.params.item}/>
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:color_theme_light.bodyBackground,
  }
});
```

My Body component with flatlist in it:

```
const Body = ({data}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    ...dataLoading....
  },[])


  return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <FlatList data={oltasok} renderItem={({item}) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setOltasDetailsVisible(true)}>
                <View style = {styles.container}>
                    ...flatlist elements....
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )} keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)} />  
    </View>
  );
}

  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    justifyContent:"space-between",
    flexDirection:"row",
    margin:20,
},
});
```

And lastly my Floating Button component:

```
const FloatingButton = ({data}) => {
    return(
    <View style={{flex:1 ,alignItems:'center', flexDirection:'row', position:'absolute',
    top:(window.height)*0.88,
    zIndex:999}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row',
                    justifyContent:'center',
                    width:'100%'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{
          marginTop:20,
          backgroundColor:color_theme_light.buttonColor,
          alignItems:'center',
          padding:13,
          borderRadius:30,
          width:200,
          position:'relative'
        }}
        onPress={() => someMethod(true)}
        >
          <Text style={{fontFamily:'QuicksandMedium',color: color_theme_light.buttonText, fontSize:17}}>Új oltás hozzáadása</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    </View>
    )
  }
```

[What I want to achieve](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/9536354/18640826/2afc497a-7e9a-11e6-8b87-d1e1f5b25532.gif)

EDIT:
You can hide the button with onEndReached={} pretty easily, now how can I show it again when the user scrolls up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a props [`onScroll`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll) for FlatList which is inherited from ScrollView. In this callback you can set the value.

Eg code :

```
....
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(true)
....
<flatList
    onScroll={()=>setShowButton(true)}
    onEndReached={()=>setShowButton(false)}
....
```

Comment: This only seems to work when you already have more items on the screen that can fit and you have to scroll down. When I tried it with two items, it instantly triggered and I can not click my button on the bottom. :/

Comment: You can set the boolean on condition based in that, like if data.length > something or any other condition which can reset the boolean to show the button

Comment: Could you please show a minimal example just with onEndReached={() => showButton(true)} and a simple <Text> because I managed to hide on scroll down, but I can not figure out how to  show it again? How could I trigger showButton(true) ? :( @Thanhal

Comment: What's your actual requirement? You only mentioned about hiding the button on reaching bottom in the question. So please update the question by clarify the requirement mentioning when to hide and when to show

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! It kinda works :D A little bit buggy, but like every second time it works. Guess it needs some polishment

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

onMomentumScrollBegin={() => setStateTo(false)}
onMomentumScrollEnd={() => setStateTo(true)}

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for placing a code. Instead, paste the code here with correct formatting.